# Why does this Mosfet get Hot?

Tags: mosfet, opto-isolator, 555, mosfet-driver, solid-state-relay

I have an IRF740 mosfet that doesn't get hot in one circuit but then gets completely hot in another identical circuit and for the life of me can not figure out why. Well the circuits aren't exactly identical but nearly so except for one or two definite things.

I'll call the circuits A and B. In circuit A the mosfet does not get hot in any way at all, in fact remains cool to the touch, even cold. While circuit B the mosfet does get hot, and this is what stumps me. Here let me explain the dilemma a little.

Circuit A is just a 555 timer triggering a divide by two circuit which is just a flip flop circuit providing a 50% duty cycle as outputs. Those outputs are alternately triggering two mosfets which are alternately switching two loads and in this case the loads are 5W 12V LED lamps. The loads being switched ON and OFF have their own power supply which is kept separate from the power supply powering both the 555 and CD4014 chips. This circuit works perfectly fine and does what it's supposed to do. Here's a pic of circuit A:

[image]

Circuit B is an identical circuit to the first except instead of switching the loads directly with mosfets it is switching and triggering two opto-isolators which then are triggering the two mosfets that are switching the LED lamp loads, again with their own power supplies.

In other words simply swap out the mosfets in circuit A with the solid state relay switches in circuit B. Here is a pic of circuit B:

[image]

Essentially these are basic home built solid state relay switches consisting of an opto-isolator and an IRF740 mosfet and a gate/source resistor of 10KΩ. Sometimes a 47Ω resistor is used between the gate and emitter of the phototransistor of the opto-coupler. This doesn't seem to help or make a difference, the mosfet still gets hot.

In circuit A the mosfet doesn't get hot at all and is nice and cool. There's more current running through the load in fact it's only a 1mA difference compared to when the load is directly connected to the power supply.

In circuit B the mosfet gets fairly hot and is very noticeable yet there is less current going through the load, this is a paradox to me.

I've tried a fet driver for the IRF740 but used another identical IRF740 as the driver, which probably doesn't work anyways, because I am probably not supposed to do that, but is all I had on hand. Driving the fet with another fet didn't even flash the LED lamp, which is weird to me. Do I need a power transistor? Is the CD4013B chip in circuit A somehow providing a type of driver that allows the mosfet to remain cool?

Fets are weird to and me and always have been, I have noticed that there is absolutely no current between the opto transistor's collector and the drain of the mosfet, maybe a few microamps, I don't know, I had it set on the largest amperage range.

The mosfet gets hot no matter what frequency the timer is set at, it doesn't change the fact the circuit A's mosfet doesn't get hot while circuit B's mosfet does.

The only real difference I see is that in circuit A the trigger current for the mosfet is being supplied by the 555's pin 3 which then enters into the clock pin on the flip flop. In circuit B the trigger circuit is being supplied by the power supply itself that is powering the load. Other than that I don't see any other differences.

I've tried increasing the gates resistance but that doesn't seem to make a difference either. I've tried no resistor on the gate at all and that doesn't seem to make a difference. I understand that a mosfet is completely different than a transistor however.

How do I get the mosfet to remain nice and cool just like it is in circuit A? Does something have to dramatically change?

Even though I am somewhat familiar to electronic circuits when it comes to this solid state relay switch I am a newbie. So if there is math involved or any other complicated explanation with unfamiliar terms be easy on me and lay it on me in a way that I can understand, basically in laymen's terms.

Comment: Your circuit B has no power supply so it can't be getting "completely hot". You can add a proper schematic using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the explanation. Circuit B does have the exact same load. I'll try to use CircuitLab. Circuit B was just to show that it replaces the mosfets in circuit B

Comment: Is the CD4013 getting hot by any chance?

Comment: @crasic No not in any way at all.

Answer (score 4):

The FETs need a few volts on the gate to turn them on.

In your 'B' circuit, that means when the FETs are on, there still has to be several volts from drain to source (Vds) to bias the gate. The power dissipated in the FET is the current multiplied by Vds, which heats the FET. The voltage drop across the FET is why the load draws less current than circuit 'A'.

In your 'A' circuit, the 4013 drives the gate, so Vds can drop to sub-volt, even millivolt, levels, for very little heating.

If you have a DMM, measure the voltage across the FET in each case when it's conducting.

You could modify your 'B' circuit like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsf4sA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Not all of these components may be needed, depending on the value of your load supply, and whether you can get a Vgg supply easily.

The important point is that the gate can be swung to +10 to +15v volts (I've drawn a GND symbol, not because the circuit needs to be grounded, but because that's the 0v reference point I'm taking all my voltages from) whatever the FET drain voltage is.

If your load supply is in the range 10-15v, then you do not need a separate Vgg supply, just connect them together, and lose D1 and R2. If your load supply V1 is a much higher voltage, then D1 and R2 serve to limit the gate volts, most FETs go bang with more than 20v, and are fully on at 15v. Or you could move D1 R2 to create a 15v Vgg from V1, or you could use a regulator to create Vgg from V1, the possibilities are endless. Note the Vgg supply does have to be connected to the FET source terminal, it can't just be floating.

If you're switching frequently, you'd probably want to reduce R1, as a high value makes for a slow turnoff. For fast switching, it would be better to have a proper buffer between the opto and the FET gate to give you a low impedance drive in both directions.

Troubleshooting - with this circuit, you ought to be able to see only mV (10 maybe, 100 if it's a very heavy load) Vds when it's on, and most of your Vgg voltage as Vgs.

Comment: Yes, and you can fix circuit B by connecting the opto collector to the separate Vcc through a resistor. Pick a resistor such that the max Vgs is not exceeded (voltage divider with the existing 10k to ground).

Comment: Or, if you need to design for a range of voltages on that separate VCC, put a zener diode in parallel with that 10k\$\Omega\$ resistor.  12-15V would probably do for most FETs (I'm too lazy to look at your FET's data sheet for you).  Look at the data sheet, and choose a Zener voltage between the \$\mathrm{V_{GS}}\$ used for it's rated \$\mathrm{R_{DS(ON)}}\$ and its rated maximum \$\mathrm{V_{GS}}\$.

Comment: @Mattman944 Thanks for the suggestion. I just now tried a resistor between the opto collector and separate Vcc and it made it even hotter. The Vgss on circuit A measures at 5.30V while circuit B has 2V. It's a bit confusing since I figured the voltage would be really high right there at the gate and source. I put as small as 1 Ohm and less and it only made the voltage go up a little bit. I'm not entirely sure if the voltage should be higher or lower, or whatever other method could be used. The mosfet is an IRF740 and the datasheet says the Vgss is + or - 30V, I'm just about baffled.

Comment: The max Vgs is higher than I expected, you don't need a resistor on the collector, or you could use a small resistor 330 or so. You tried 1 ohm so that is not the problem. You have a second problem, the transistor isn't saturating. Increase the gate to ground resistor (100k?) or decrease the LED resistor. You need to get the voltage from the collector to the emitter much lower so the gate voltage is higher.

Comment: @Mattman944 Ok, so I heeded your suggestion of increasing the gate and source resistor to 100k, and it seemed to improve slightly as the gate source voltage went up only by a little bit from something like 2.09V to 2.19. Sorry, laptop editing is entirely different than cell phone editing and so hitting a space posts! Anyways, so I eliminated it altogether and the volts shot up to around 4.14V and slowly decreased. This is close I think to circuit "A" both the 100k and no resistor starts out cool but eventually heats up. I can't figure out the opto ratings despite the datasheet, for the H11D3.

Comment: @Mattman944 I really wish these comments would allow for just a little bit more space to get any kind of real answers to real questions, anyways I should mention that I believe this is the right track, and I don't get a clear answer on the opto datasheet, and I don't want to blow those because I have a limited amount of those which is why the 330Ω is there. However having the 100kΩ helps it a little bit, but this would lower the switch off time wouldn't it? I'm cycling at least a few thousand times. So I guess there's a trade off there, but knowing how low of a resistor on the LED would help!

Comment: @MarcStriebeck Comments are not supposed to be for answers, answers have plenty of space for real answers. When I posted my short answer yesterday, I supposed that analysing the problem would be sufficient to point to the solution. Obviously not so, so I have added a small variety of solutions (see text for their differences). If any of these aren't clear, or you want it spelled out how to connect a buffer in there, just ask again.

Comment: @Neil_UK - sorry to hijack your answer, I sensed that the OP needed a nudge in the right direction, and it didn't seem appropriate to create my own answer.

Comment: @Mattman944 *au contraire*, if you see that the OP doesn't understand an answer, for whatever reason, get stuck in and generate your own, addressing specifically the point you've seen, and you can post a schematic. It's almost always clearer than having to wade through a long comment trail. In addition, comments are volatile, and can be removed by mods 'tidying up' a long discussion. Reference the other's answer in your own if it makes you feel more appropriate. This site and community appear to be fairly ego-free, the one user who used to bite now seems to have left.

Comment: To all users, It's fine if these comments get deleted, except the ones that do clarify and *point to* an answer. Neil_UK, there is no question as to what you have shown, except you did not notice that all these solutions have already been offered by Mattman944 in these comments, however I am grateful. Mattman944 you mentioned in a comment "You need to get the voltage from the collector to the emitter much lower so the gate voltage is higher", could you clarify this please, you mean the opto?  Neil_UK, your first half answer makes sense in that the fet is clearly not getting enough current.

Comment: @MarcStriebeck 'fet not getting enough current' doesn't make sense. Fet not getting enough voltage might might a little more sense, except that it's not quite true. The fet **is** getting enough gate voltage to turn it on, the problem is that to get that gate voltage, it's raising its drain voltage excessively, which results in high dissipation. The solution is to give the fet adequate gate voltage, independent of the drain voltage.

Comment: @Neil_UK You are right, I can't tolerate how I was taken away from my last post and when I came back to edit the *current* to *voltage*, like you just mentioned, that the time allowed to edit had expired! I suppose that's my fault for having an emergency. Anyways, yes, that is right, and that is what I was going to edit but, apparently is now way too late. So yes, I didn't mean current but **voltage**.  Ok, so it's not the gs causing the heat, it's actually the drain and the gs *is getting enough* voltage.So you're saying that it's using it's own power supply instead of the opto's volt supply.

Comment: @MarcStriebeck Version B drives the gate from the drain, so the drain can't go lower voltage than the several volts that the gate demands. So if you want the drain to go down near 0v to reduce the dissipation, power = Vds * Ids, then you need to drive the gate from a supply, not the drain terminal. Perhaps the supply to the load would be an appropriate voltage?

Comment: @Neil_UK I am not entirely sure what you mean by how the drain is driving the gate. The drain is going straight to the gate? Instead of the source going to gate to drive it? The supply to the load I thought was already tried with the resistor connected to the opto collector to positive of the load supply, which didn't do anything. Both fet sources have to be kept separated from each other hence the relays. What about using the chips supply to trigger the gate, or optos in series, or even a fet driver? There's got to be a way with the separate power supply, after all it's 12.33V.

Comment: @MarcStriebeck I'm giving up on this, I think you're either deliberately misunderstanding for amusement, as in [this sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3YiPC91QUk), or you are beyond explaining things to. In either case, I'm not the one to help you.

Comment: @Neil_UK No! Don't say that. I am sure what you meant and just now got it working correctly, just at the limit allowed for extended discussion in comments. The fix was simple and staring me in the face the whole time, strangely enough. In version **A** the opto collector needed to be *completely* disconnected from the drain of the fet and connected to the positive of the load's power supply with a 330Ω resistor. This was done before but it wasn't made clear, at least I didn't think it was. Thank you for helping make this a clear solution, I really appreciate it very much. Credit to all users.